# Can you SetOnClickListener for viewpager2?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to show a message when the user clicks on the page in `viewPager2`. I tried this but didn't work.

here my adapter code. what I am trying to do is when the user clicks on the page shows a massage.

```
public class Page extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Page.ViewHolder> {


@NonNull


ArrayList<List_page> list = new ArrayList<>();

public Page(ArrayList<List_page> list) {
    this.list = list;


}


public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.Book_page, parent, false);


    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.setImg(list.get(position).getImg());



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
```

Comment: It's not the right way of doing so. You should set `OnClickListener` on every page item in `onBindViewHolder` function of your `ViewPager2`'s adapter if you are using `RecyclerView.Adapter`. If you show your adapter's code, may be I can help you out. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.setImg(list.get(position).getImg());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```